# SFML C++ Canny edge detection double edges

Tags: c++, image-processing, sfml, canny-operator, sobel

So, I decided to create a simple Canny edge detector just as exercise before biting harder topics with image processing.

I tried to follow the typical path of Canny:
 1. Grayscaling the image
 2. Gaussian filter to blur the noise
 3. Edge detection - I use both Sobel and Scharr
 4. Edge thinning - I used non-maximum suppression in direction depending on gradient direction - vertical, horizontal, 45 diagonal or 135 diagonal
 5. Hysteresis

I somehow managed to get it working with Scharr's detection but I have recurring problem with double or multiple edges, espacially with Sobel. I can't really find a set of parameters which will make it work.

My algorithm for Sobel:

```
void sobel(sf::Image &image, pixldata **garray, float division)
{
int t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0, t4 = 0;
sf::Color color;
sf::Image bufor;
bufor.create(image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, sf::Color::Cyan);

for (int i = 1;i < image.getSize().y - 1;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1;j < image.getSize().x - 1;j++)
    {

        t1 = (- image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r - 2 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r - image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r + image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r + 2 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r) / division;
        t2 = (- image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r - 2 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r - image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r + image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + 2 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r + image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r) / division;
        t3 = (- image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r - 2 * image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r - image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r + image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r + 2 * image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r + image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r) / division;
        t4 = (- image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r - 2 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r - image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r + 2 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r + image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r) / division;

        color.r = (abs(t1) + abs(t2) + abs(t3) + abs(t4));
        color.g = (abs(t1) + abs(t2) + abs(t3) + abs(t4));
        color.b = (abs(t1) + abs(t2) + abs(t3) + abs(t4));

        garray[j][i].gx = t1;
        garray[j][i].gy = t3;
        garray[j][i].gtrue = sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4);
        garray[j][i].gsimpl = sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2);

        t1 = abs(t1);
        t2 = abs(t2);
        t3 = abs(t3);
        t4 = abs(t4);

        if (t1 > t4 && t1 > t3 && t1 > t2)
            garray[j][i].fi = 0;
        else if (t2 > t4 && t2 > t3 && t2 > t1)
            garray[j][i].fi = 45;
        else if (t3 > t4 && t3 > t2 && t3 > t1)
            garray[j][i].fi = 90;
        else if (t4 > t3 && t4 > t2 && t4 > t1)
            garray[j][i].fi = 135;
        else
            garray[j][i].fi = 0;

        if (sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4) < 0)
        {
            color.r = 0;
            color.g = 0;
            color.b = 0;
        }
        else if (sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4) > 255)
        {
            color.r = 255;
            color.g = 255;
            color.b = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            color.r = sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4);
            color.g = sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4);
            color.b = sqrt(t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3 + t4*t4);
        }
        bufor.setPixel(j, i, color);
    }
}
image.copy(bufor, 0, 0);
}
```

Code for Scharr differs only in multiplying the pixels' values.

```
        t1 = (-3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r - 10 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r - 3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r + 10 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r) / division;
        t2 = (-3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r - 10 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r - 3 * image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + 10 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r) / division;
        t3 = (-3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i + 1).r - 10 * image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r - 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r + 10 * image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i - 1).r) / division;
        t4 = (-3 * image.getPixel(j, i + 1).r - 10 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i + 1).r - 3 * image.getPixel(j + 1, i).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i).r + 10 * image.getPixel(j - 1, i - 1).r + 3 * image.getPixel(j, i - 1).r) / division;
```

Thinning code:

```
void intelligentThin(sf::Image &image, int radius, pixldata **garray)
{
int xmax = image.getSize().x;
int ymax = image.getSize().y;
bool judgeandjury = true;

for (int i = 0;i < xmax;i++)
{
    int leftBound = 0, rightBound = 0, ceilBound = 0, bottomBound = 0;

    if (i < radius)
    {
        leftBound = 0;
        rightBound = i + radius;
    }
    else if (i >= xmax - radius)
    {
        leftBound = i - radius;
        rightBound = xmax - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBound = i - radius;
        rightBound = i + radius;
    }

    for (int j = 0;j < ymax;j++)
    {
        if (j < radius)
        {
            ceilBound = 0;
            bottomBound = j + radius;
        }
        else if (j >= ymax - radius)
        {
            ceilBound = j - radius;
            bottomBound = ymax - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ceilBound = j - radius;
            bottomBound = j + radius;
        }

        if (garray[i][j].fi == 0)
        {
            for (int t = leftBound; t <= rightBound; t++)
            {
                if ((image.getPixel(t, j).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r) && (t != i))
                {
                    judgeandjury = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (garray[i][j].fi == 135)
        {
            for (int l = leftBound, t = ceilBound; (l <= rightBound && t <= bottomBound); l++, t++)
            {
                if ((image.getPixel(l, t).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r) && (t != j))
                {
                    judgeandjury = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (garray[i][j].fi == 90)
        {
            for (int t = ceilBound; t <= bottomBound; t++)
            {
                if ((image.getPixel(i, t).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r) && (t != j))
                {
                    judgeandjury = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (garray[i][j].fi == 45)
        {
            for (int l = rightBound, t = ceilBound; (l >= leftBound && t <= bottomBound); l--, t++)
            {
                if ((image.getPixel(l, t).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r) && (t != j))
                {
                    judgeandjury = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (judgeandjury == false)
        {
            image.setPixel(i, j, sf::Color::Black);
        }

        judgeandjury = true;

    }
    leftBound = rightBound = 0;
}
}
```

Hysteresis code:

```
void hysteresis(sf::Image &image, int radius, int uplevel, int lowlevel)
{

int xmax = image.getSize().x;
int ymax = image.getSize().y;
bool judgeandjury = false;

sf::Image bufor;
bufor.create(image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, sf::Color::Cyan);

for (int i = 0;i < xmax;i++)
{
    int leftBound = 0, rightBound = 0, ceilBound = 0, bottomBound = 0;

    if (i < radius)
    {
        leftBound = 0;
        rightBound = i + radius;
    }
    else if (i >= xmax - radius)
    {
        leftBound = i - radius;
        rightBound = xmax - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBound = i - radius;
        rightBound = i + radius;
    }

    for (int j = 0;j < ymax;j++)
    {
        int currentPoint = image.getPixel(i, j).r;

        if (j < radius)
        {
            ceilBound = 0;
            bottomBound = j + radius;
        }
        else if (j >= ymax - radius)
        {
            ceilBound = j - radius;
            bottomBound = ymax - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ceilBound = j - radius;
            bottomBound = j + radius;
        }

        if (currentPoint > uplevel)
        {
            judgeandjury = true;
        }
        else if (currentPoint > lowlevel)
        {
            for (int t = leftBound; t <= rightBound; t++)
            {
                for (int l = ceilBound; l <= bottomBound; l++)
                {
                    if (image.getPixel(t, l).r > uplevel)
                    {
                        judgeandjury = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else judgeandjury = false;

        if (judgeandjury == true)
        {
            bufor.setPixel(i, j, sf::Color::White);
        }
        else
        {
            bufor.setPixel(i, j, sf::Color::Black);
        }

        judgeandjury = false;
        currentPoint = 0;

    }
    leftBound = rightBound = 0;
}
image.copy(bufor, 0, 0);
}
```

The results are quite unsatisfactionary for Sobel:

[Thinning the Sobel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1AM5.png)

[Sobel after hysteresis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy4i9.png)

With Scharr the results are way better:

[Thinned Scharr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZIVm.png)

[Scharr after hysteresis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL2mS.png)

Set of parameters:

```
#define thinsize 1                  
#define scharrDivision 1        
#define sobelDivision 1                 
#define hysteresisRadius 1          
#define level 40                    
#define hysteresisUpperLevelSobel 80        
#define hysteresisLowerLevelSobel 60        
#define hysteresisUpperLevelScharr 200      
#define hysteresisLowerLevelScharr 100
```

As you can see, there is a problem with Sobel, which generate double edges. Scharr also generates some noise but I think it's acceptable. Of course, it always can get better, if someone could give some advice :)

What is the cause of this behaviour? Does it result from my mistakes or poor algorithms or maybe is it just a case of parameters?

EDIT:
posting main()

```
sf::Image imydz;
imydz.loadFromFile("lena.jpg");
int x = imydz.getSize().x;
int y = imydz.getSize().y;


pixldata **garray = new pixldata *[x];
for (int i = 0;i < x;i++)
{
garray[i] = new pixldata[y];
}


monochrome(imydz);
gauss(imydz, radius, sigma);

//sobel(imydz, garray, sobelDivision);

scharr(imydz, garray, scharrDivision);

intelligentThin(imydz, thinsize, garray);
hysteresis(imydz, hysteresisRadius, hysteresisUpperLevel, hysteresisLowerLevel);
```

Second edit - repaired suppression:

```
sf::Image bufor;
bufor.create(image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, sf::Color::Black);
for (int i = 1;i < xmax - 1;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1;j < ymax - 1;j++)
    {
        if (garray[i][j].fi == 0)
        {
            if (((image.getPixel(i, j).r >= image.getPixel(i + 1, j).r) && (image.getPixel(i, j).r > image.getPixel(i - 1, j).r)) ||
                ((image.getPixel(i, j).r > image.getPixel(i + 1, j).r) && (image.getPixel(i, j).r >= image.getPixel(i - 1, j).r)))
            {
                judgeandjury = true;
            }
            else judgeandjury = false;
        }
...
 if (judgeandjury == false)
        {
            bufor.setPixel(i, j, sf::Color::Black);
        }
        else bufor.setPixel(i, j, image.getPixel(i, j));
        judgeandjury = false;
    }
}
image.copy(bufor, 0, 0);
```

[Repaired Scharr on Lena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XGxf.png)
It seems strange
[Another test image - strange results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C0rN.png)

[Before binarization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0CZN.png)

[Ready gears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFisi.png)

Comment: Your thinning process generates double edges (even for Scharr); in fact more than double. Where did you get this weird thinning code ?

Comment: That is quite a mountain of code you expect us to read through, plus a heap of milks, plus no well-defined question. Please try and make this more *minimal*.

Comment: The problem is in your "thinning", so post that code, with suitable inputs and a `main()`, so we can try to reproduce your problem. By the way, the Canny edge detector uses **non-maximum suppression**, not **thinning**. Thinning is a whole different concept.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably rewrite that "thinning" algorithm of yours from scratch. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression) for how this algorithm should work. You don't need the loops over `l` and `t`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust hmm, this is purely my invention. I created it after reading the basics from wikipedia and a book. Could you indicate, what are the problems with this solution?

Comment: @CrisLuengo added main. I just used wikipedia to create this from scratch, I couldn't really think of the mistakes here myself. I know that it is non-maximum suppression, jsut calling this "thinning" :D

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski: sorry, I don't intend to reverse engineer your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't read your whole code in detail, there is much too much code there. But obviously your non-maximum suppression code is wrong. Let's look at what it does for one pixel in the middle of the image, where the gradient is close to 0 degrees:

```
leftBound = i - radius;
rightBound = i + radius;
// ...
for (int t = leftBound; t <= rightBound; t++)
{
   if ((image.getPixel(t, j).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r) && (t != i))
   {
      judgeandjury = false; // it's not a maximum: suppress
   }
}
// ...
if (judgeandjury == false)
{
   image.setPixel(i, j, sf::Color::Black);
}
```

Here, `radius` is set to 1 by the calling code. Any other value would be bad, so this is OK. I would remove that as a parameter altogether. Now your loop is:

```
for (int t = i-1; t <= t+1; t++)
   if (t != i)
```

This means that you hit exactly two values of `t`. So this should of course be replaced with simpler code that does not loop, it will be more readable.

This is what it now does:

```
if (   (image.getPixel(i-1, j).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r)
    || (image.getPixel(i+1, j).r >= image.getPixel(i, j).r)) {
   judgeandjury = false; // it's not a maximum: suppress
}
```

So you suppress the pixel if it is not strictly larger than its neighbors. Looking back at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression), it seems that they suggest the same. But in fact, this is not correct, you want the point to be strictly larger than one of the two neighbors, and larger or equal to the other. This prevents the situation where the gradient happens to be equally strong on two neighboring pixels. The actual maximum can fall right in the middle of two pixels, yielding two pixels on this local maximum gradient with exactly the same value. But let's ignore this case for now, it is possible but not all that likely.

Next, you suppress the maximum... **in the input image**! This means that, when you reach the next pixel on this line, you will compare its value to this value that was just suppressed. Of course it will be larger, even though it was smaller than the original value at that location. That is, non-maxima will look like maxima because you put a neighboring pixel to 0.

So: write the result of the algorithm to an output image:

```
if (judgeandjury == true)
{
   output.setPixel(i, j, image.getPixel(i, j));
}
```

...which of course you need to allocate, but you already know that.

---

Your second problem is in the `sobel` function, where you compute the gradient magnitude. It clips (saturates) the output. By cutting values of the output above 255 to 255, you create very broad lines along the edges of a constant value. The test of the non-maximum suppression is satisfied at the two edges of this line, but not in the middle, where pixels have the same value as both its neighbors.

To solve this, either:

1. Use a floating-point buffer to store the gradient magnitude. Here you don’t need to worry about data ranges.
2. Divide the magnitude by some value such that it will never exceed 255. Now you’re quantifying the magnitude rather than clipping it. Quantizing *should* be fine in this case.

I strongly recommend that you follow (1). I typically use floating-point—values images for everything, and only convert to 8-bit ints for display. This simplified a lot of things!

Comment: Thank you sir, it helped with Lena picture. I added new code in the post above with your suggestions applied. I also posted new Lena and a result from another image which looks quite strange. Somehow, it draws two edges 'around' the proper one. Could you explain that?

Comment: @Tomasz: Does the output of the non-maximum suppression look better now, or does this one also show these double edges?

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski: you must show the results of the thinning (obviously still wrong), not after binarization as this hides all information.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it looks better for Lena but it looks very weird for another image - the double edges are now moved aside from each other. I attached 3 new images to the post, so you can see the results

Comment: @YvesDaoust I attached image of Lena before binarization/hysteresis. Gears image looks all the same before/after binarization

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski: ok, your choice not to show it. Your thinning is abnormal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I attached the image

Comment: @TomaszMałachowski: your thinning behaves as another edge detector: It creates edges... on both sides of the edges, i.e. where there are large variations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you so much, it helped :) I created the array of gradients ('garray') previously but didn't think about using this instead of getting the color magnitude. So I chose the (1) solution. I uploaded image of the gears with now correct algorithm so you could see the result :) Thanks again :)

Comment: @Tomasz: excellent! Glad it helped. There are other refinements you can look into if interested. For example, it is best to use Gaussian gradients, rather than Gaussian smoothing and some other gradient. Most people implement it as you did, but the original Canny paper goes to great lengths to show that Gaussian gradients are the best choice!

Comment: @CrisLuengo of course, I will further improve this program and thanks to you, now I have a working base to work with as a newbie to image processing & computer vision. OpenCV's waiting for me :D Best regards!